# Is it possible to prevent linebreaks between hyphenated words in CSS?

Tags: html, css, word-break

While CSS has `word-break` to better control display of long words, is it possible to do the reverse by preserving hyphenated words without been forcefully broken into 2 separate lines?

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYyENV) to better illustrate the scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try using "non-breaking hyphen"? No CSS needed. It's a normal html entity.

Try this `&#8209;`

This is an example

```html
Sample&#8209;text
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, thank you. Your solute led me to http://graphemica.com/%E2%80%91 , which named the character "non-breaking hyphen".

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**
Your question reads, that you are trying to undo word-break but want to substitute it with hyphens instead. the following should help

If this is not what you wanted, I apologise this is how it read to me.

**Try this out**

```
.myClass{
  -moz-hyphens: none;
  -ms-hyphens: none;
  -webkit-hyphens: none;
  hyphens: none;
}
```

Note if there is a hyphen in the word anyway it will carriage return it

To avoid it carriage returning a hyphenated word, and force it to be 1 word, then it would be via javascript, you will need to alter the text of "-" to an HTML entity which is what the other person was suggesting

Comment: Added a CodePen demo to illustrate my question.

Comment: Amended my reply above, please note if the word already has a hyphen in it, then it will carriage return it because thats gramatically correct so the only way around this is JS